Use VBA to have dropdown menu on one sheet change dropdown menu on second sheet
I'm fairly new to using Excel VBA and looking for some help troubleshooting the code I'm using.
I have a sheet in a workbook with a dropdown menu that I would like to have change the value on another drop down sheet.
For example, if sheet1 dropdown menu selects "1", Sheet2 menu also changes to "1".
The code I'm using is:
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    
    
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Scenario Manager")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("DASH")
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, ws2.Range("D8")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ws1.Range("H28").Value = Target.Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
     
End Sub

However after I save the module, DASH dropdown menu does not change the menu on Scenario Manager.
This is in a macro-enabled workbook.
Any guidance would be much appreciated.
I have checked that the workbook can actually run macros (it can)
Tried reversing the worksheet titles (no effect)

Is this code stored in the sheet code module?

So correct me if I am wrong.. sheet1 dropdown menu selects "1", Sheet2 menu also changes to "1". Similarly if user selects "1" in sheet2 dropdown menu, Sheet1 menu also changes to "1".  Should work both ways?

It's not stored in a specific sheet, but in a modules folder under the workbook.
It doesn't need to go both ways (fine if it does) but definitely need the DASH sheet to effect the Scenario Manager sheet

If you need it one way, for example DASH sheet to effect the Scenario Manager sheet, then you need to put the code in the sheet code area of DASH and not in a module or ThisWorkbook Code area. Right click on the sheet tab and click on view code.

And if you want it to work both ways then the code goes in the ThisWorkbook Code area. And of course you have to then use Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range) instead of Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) You code will also have to be modified to work both ways...

One final and important point. Since you are working with Worksheet_Change event, you may want to give THIS a quick read.

Thanks everyone, as Siddharth recommended, I needed to put it in the sheet itself.  That fixed it.  Also thank you for the link with expanded info on the event.  I'll be sure to incorporate that into the code.
